# How to fix to use TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi, tls1.2

I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, .Net 4.7.
And using DocuSign SOAP APIs to send an envelope. My code is using .NET 4.7 - checked in web.config and confirmed in project properties > Application tab.

And yet, I keep getting the error from DocuSign that I need to use TLS 1.2 and that I am using TLS 1.

What else can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] showing your code and the config.

Comment: The web.config has 4.7. Project properties also shows 4.7.When I send an envelope, i get the error that I am at TLS 1. This was working until Feb. 4th.

Comment: It's one thing to describe your app. It's quite another to show the exact code and config and a proper MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always force the TLS version yourself with:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

However, this shouldn't be necessary under .NET Framework 4.7.  TLS 1.2 is the default.

See also [this blog post from Docusign](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-updating-applications-end-tls-1-0/).

Comment: Sorry Matt, but version 2.1.10 of what? I am using SOAP APIs for DocuSign. I have .NET 4.7. I can see that in web.config as well in project properties.  And also in registry that is the default version. IIS 10 is bound to CLR 4. I have also seen all those blogs, they do not talk about it. As for reporting bug, this change came to be last year according to DocuSign, so I would think they would have fixed by now.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and thought you were using their C# client.   Edited my post accordingly.  Did you try setting TLS12 manually?  You can do that anywhere in your code before you make the call to the API, preferably just once on application startup.  Also, there is a lot more detail from Microsoft on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls).

Comment: Added that line and still the same message. Do I have to add at every call or only when I first instantiate the APIClient?

Comment: It only needs to be added once, but really shouldn't be necessary on net47 anyways - so I guess there's something else going on.  Sorry, I'm not certain why.  Maybe if you can help others repro the issue in your question, that might lead to a solution.